# If $\vec{F}=-\nabla V$ and $V ∝ 1/r^2$, then shouldn't objects fly up instead of fall down?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, vector-fields

If the apple moves from the higher potential to lower potential $(\vec{F}=-\nabla V)$ and the closer the distance the higher potential $(V ∝ 1/r^2)$, then shouldn't the apple fly up instead of fall down?

Comment: The potential is negative: $V\propto -1/r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you would think that. For the potential we have:
$$V(\mathbf x) = - \frac{GMm}{r}$$
From which the force is:
$$\mathbf F = -\boldsymbol \nabla V(\mathbf x) = -\frac{GMm}{r^2}  \mathbf {\hat {r}}$$
Which is an attractive force between the two objects $M$ and $m$.

Comment: is the minus sign a convention, or does it have a specific meaning? And which object has the potential energy, so that it can be converted to kinetic energy? Both?

Comment: The minus sign in the potential energy comes from the fact that the potential at infinity is taken to be zero by convention.  However, even if you don't take the reference point for zero potential at infinity, $V(\mathbf x)$ would only be shifted by a constant amount; meaning that the force would not change (because the derivative of a constant is zero).

Comment: Also, both the earth and the object posses gravitational potential energy that can be converted into kinetic energy. However, the mass of earth is so much bigger than the object that the velocity for earth associated with this kinetic energy is utterly negligible.
You can also interpret the minus sign in the potential as indication that the energy decreases as the object gets closer to the ground.